# videojs-contrib-dash format not supported with webpack

Tags: webpack, video.js, mpeg-dash

I want to do a plyer supporting Mpeg-DASH. So i use Webpack and video.js with videojs-contrib-dash plugin:

```
import videojs from 'video.js'
import 'videojs-contrib-dash'


export default {
  name: 'videojs',
  props: ['src'],
  mounted () {
    let player = videojs(this.$el)

    player.ready(function () {
      player.src({
        src: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/_bc_dml/example-content/sintel_dash/sintel_vod.mpd',
        type: 'application/dash+xml'
      })
      player.play()
    })
  }
}
```

(I use Vue.js)

But, I doesn't work. I get an error in the console `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`

Answer (score 0):

The `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED` indicates that the [browser does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError/code) the stream (e.g. the codec or container format). However, this depends on the browser and/or operating system. The codec and container format used in the manifest look fine, they should play on most platforms.

I did a quick check and the stream simply did nothing (also no error) for me in [dash.js](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/v2.4.1/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html), which is used by videojs-contrib-dash. Another check with other players, like the [Bitmovin Player](http://bitmovin.com/hls-mpeg-dash-test-player/), worked without any problems, so this might be somehow a player bug.

Answer (score 0):

This works... I tested it as a nuxt.js app.
I changed the following: you can load the modules inside the script tag. Then control the options in the video tag inside the template tag.

```
<template>

<section data-sr id="dash" class="dash u-full-width">
    <div class="video-background">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="bgvid" autoplay loop loop="true" muted controls="false" setScheduleWhilePaused="true"
          setFastSwitchEnabled="true">
         <source src="https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</template>

<script>
import '../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css'
import videojs from 'video.js'
import 'dashjs'
import 'videojs-contrib-dash'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```